# How to perform a *Fast* DCT (Discrete Cosine Transform) in R?

Tags: r, fft, dct

Using Rprof revealed the dct in the dtt package to be the main offender in a piece of R code that was running quite slowly. Swapping it out for fft in the stats package (which is not the same transformation, but should take the same time to compute) my run time improved dramatically. In fact 2/3 of my Rprof lines were dct calls previously and a mere 3 lines of about 600 were fft calls after making the switch.

Is the dct implementation in the dtt package not done using the **fast** discrete fourier transform? If so, is there a package that does have one? (I know one could double ones data, then extract coefficients for the dct from those fft coefficients, but a straight fast dct would certainly be nicer, and there really *ought* to be one somewhere).

Comment: Try to avoid the negative (and thus appearing to be the devil's advocate / combatant poster) in titles ;-)

Comment: `library(sos); findFn("fast fourier cosine transform")` reveals an `rfft` function in the `wavethresh`.  It looks like it works by a packing/unpacking mechanism -- based on a rusty memory of *Numerical Recipes* this could probably be done even more efficiently, but maybe it's useful?

Comment: I understand what motivation there might be for dct not to use the fast dct. One, the fast dct is much, much harder to write. Also a vector of size N the speedup of the fast dct depends on the prime factorization of N. So some dct versions will just pad the vector to the next biggest power of 2 for performance, but then the coefficients returned aren't really "the" dct coefficients of that vector as they are affected by the padding. At the same time, in situations where N can be chosen to be a power of 2 in the first place, having the fast version gives an insane performance increase.

Answer (score 12):

There appears to be no fast dct, but there is an fft (fast fourier transform) in the stats package, so here is how you could go about getting the fast dct using fft.

**Use this at your own risk. I haven't done any serious checking of it. I checked it on a couple of vectors of different sizes and it gave the same results as function dct in package dtt on those.** If anyone wants to double check me by comparing it to the output from dct then feel free to do so and post your results.

Take your vector and extend it to a vector twice as long as follows: If your vector is v=(1,2,3) then double the entries to w=(1,2,3,3,2,1). *Note the ordering.* If your vector is v=(1,2,4,9) then double the entries to w=(1,2,4,9,9,4,2,1)

Let N be the length of your ORIGINAL vector (before you doubled its length).

Then the first N coefficients of 
.5 * fft(w)/exp(complex(imaginary=pi / 2 / N)*(seq(2*N)-1))
should agree with computing 
dct(v)
except it should be dramatically faster in almost all cases.

**Speed considerations**. If you prime factor N then the time it takes to compute the fast dct is like the time it takes to do a slow dct for each of those prime factors. So if N is 2^K it is like doing a K different slow dct transforms on a vector of length two, so its *really* fast. If N is prime (worst case scenario) then there is no speed up at all. The greatest speedup is on vectors that are a power of two in length.

**Note: The R code above looks incredibly unfriendly, so let me say what is going on.** After doubling the length in the right way, the first N coefficients of the fft you get are *almost* the right thing. However the coefficients need to be tweaked a bit. Let P stand for e^(pi * i / 2 / N). Leave the first coefficient alone. Divide the second coefficient by P, divide the third by P^2, divide the fourth by P^3, etc... Then divide *all* the coefficients by 2 (including the first one) to agree with the normalization R uses for the dct.

This *should* give the same thing as using the dct function in package dtt but be dramatically faster in almost all cases.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: I have never used the `dtt` package and cannot compare my results to its results. My answer is generic regarding DCT/FFT.**

John's idea is correct, but he is two-off regarding repeating the vector and has to compensate it by tweaking the coefficients (the `e^(pi * i / 2 / N)` factor). With the right extension of the original vector, the FFT produces directly correct results(*). To quote from [Wikipedia](http://[Wikipedia][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform]):

"*The DCT-I is exactly equivalent (up to an overall scale factor of 2), to a DFT of 2N-2 real numbers with even symmetry. For example, a DCT-I of N=5 real numbers abcde is exactly equivalent to a DFT of eight real numbers abcdedcb (even symmetry), divided by two.*"

I.e., if we have a vector `v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` on which we wish to perform the DCT, we should construct a new vector `w = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2]` and perform the FFT on it. Notice that the first and the last component of `v` appear only once in `w`, in the original order!

This works because Fourier transform of an even function (function symmetric around zero) consists purely of real (cosine) coefficients. If we'd construct the vector `w` by including the whole reversed `v`, as John suggested, it would be symmetric around `-0.5`. Due to this tiny shift the Fourier transform would  also produce imaginary (sine) coefficients.

(*) The method here produces DCT-I. John's method seems to aim at DCT-II.

Answer (score 2):

Both John and Igor are correct in their answers, but I thought they lacked some example code.

```
library(dtt)

par(mfrow=c(3, 1), mar=c(2, 3, 1, 0.1), mgp=c(2, 0.8, 0))

set.seed(1)
N <- 60
v <- sin(seq(0, pi*2*4, l=N))/2 + 
     sin(seq(0, pi*2*7, l=N))/3 + 
     sin(seq(0, pi*2*15, l=N))/2 + 
     runif(N, -1, 1)/40 +
     runif(N, -1, 1)/40

plot(v, type="o")
```

**DCT-I:**

```
v.dct1 <- dct(v, variant=1)

w <- c(v, v[(N - 1):2])
w.dct1 <- 0.5 * Re(fft(w)[1:N])


plot(v.dct1, type="l", col="#00000088")
abline(h=0, col="#00000044")
lines(w.dct1, col=2, lty=3, lwd=2)
legend("topright", c("dtt::dct", "fft"), bty="n", col=1:2, lwd=1)
legend("topleft", "DCT-I", bty="n")
```

**DCT-II:**

```
v.dct2 <- dct(v, variant=2)

P <- exp(complex(imaginary=pi / 2 / N)*(seq(2*N)-1)) 

w <- c(v, v[N:1])
w.dct2 <- 0.5 * Re(fft(w)[1:N]/P)

plot(v.dct2, type="l", col="#00000088")
abline(h=0, col="#00000044")
lines(w.dct2, col=2, lty=3, lwd=2)
legend("topright", c("dtt::dct", "fft"), bty="n", col=1:2, lwd=1)
legend("topleft", "DCT-II", bty="n")
```

[image]

Comment: In DCT-II should it be `0.5 * Re(fft(w) / P)[1:N]`? When I do it this way, my results agree with `dtt::dct`, but doing it as written, by vector is still doubled.