# Transform numeric vector to specific length n R

Tags: r, vector

I have numeric vectors of different lengths and want to "standardize" their length to, say, 100 to make them comparable and transform the raw signal to a smoother version.

I do need control over the length and 'smoothing' parameters so I used the [`get_dct_transform`](https://rdrr.io/cran/syuzhet/man/get_dct_transform.html) function from the `syuzhet` package.

However, this is not super efficient with larger raw vectors:

```
set.seed(123)
sample_space = seq(-2, 2, .01)
a = sample(sample_space, 1000, replace = T)
b = sample(sample_space, 10000, replace = T)
c = sample(sample_space, 100000, replace = T)

system.time(syuzhet::get_dct_transform(raw_values = a, low_pass_size = 5))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.020   0.000   0.021 

system.time(syuzhet::get_dct_transform(raw_values = b, low_pass_size = 5))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.562   0.370   1.937 

system.time(syuzhet::get_dct_transform(raw_values = c, low_pass_size = 5))
#    user  system elapsed 
# 152.802  27.118 180.223
```

Are there faster ways of doing these kinds of transformations (DCT or FT) in R?

Another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215162/how-to-perform-a-fast-dct-discrete-cosine-transform-in-r) suggested the `fft` function but I'd need direct control over the length and filter parameter. Same issue for the [`emuR::dct`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/emuR/versions/2.0.4/topics/dct).

I'm not married to the DCT - other methods to transform a vector of length *v* to an 'smoothed' vector of length *n* would also be okay.